# Arduino diagrams

Tags: documentation

I would like to document some of the experiments I have been doing with the arduino.
In many of the internet posts on Arduino projects, they have a similar diagram of the Uno or Mega with breadboards and resistors.  Some with more detail than others.  I've been looking at many of these articles to see if they mention what drawing package they are using but nobody seems to do so.

I could take one of them and just colour out the wires but I can't get the right shade of grey or green.

[image: Arduino Uno]

1. What diagramming tool can be used for drawing these diagrams?
2. Where can I get hold of a blank Arduino Mega/Uno/Nano template.

Comment: https://fritzing.org/

Comment: Found that you can also do this on https://www.tinkercad.com  Currently, it only does Uno.  This one has a built in simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Juraj commented, those kinds of pictorial diagram are often made using a program called Fritzing.

You should also try producing a more traditional and useful diagram called a schematic. Fritzing can do that at the same time. There are also free programs that are better. See KiCAD, Eagle, EasyEDA etc.

You might find online emulators like Wokwa to be usefull.

---

Related:

Many of the [Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/28251/2191) also apply to Fritzing's pictorial diagrams.